# First Post Intro & Migration Question

Tags: software-installation, install, dell

I just joined the elementaryOS forum as I am strongly considering replacing my server OS with elementary.  I have a Dell r710 (2xXeon CPU, 64GB, 4TB HDD) currently running LXLE but I need to rebuild it to add more HDD storage, and will have to install a fresh OS.  So...  I use a Mac mostly for my personal use and thus I like the UI of elementary.  I note that it is based on the same Ubuntu base (bionic beaver, 18.04 LTS), so I would think I could replace my OS without any difficulty.

I run VMware Workstation Pro for work, and I recently installed Plex Media Server for personal use, and neither are listed in elementary's App Center.  Will I be able to integrate them easily or will I need to use the CLI (I'm an old CLI guy, so that isn't a deal-killer)?  Are there any known issues I should consider?  I know that I ran into a hardware compatibility issue with CentOS when I tried to install it, so I don't want to spend an entire week building up this refurbished server.

Thanks, everyone.  I look forward to being a part of the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since LXLE and elementary OS are both based on the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS release you shouldn't have much in the way issues when it comes to compatibility.
Keep in mind that incompatibilities may arise for anything coupled to LXDE since Pantheon is the desktop environment used on elementary OS, though this may not be an issue for you given your server-oriented use case.

Since elementary OS is intended for desktop use, it doesn't come with as much out-of-box support for running server-side applications such as Plex Media Server.
AppCenter is meant for discovering and installing desktop applications, third-party drivers, and managing system updates.
That said, its based on Ubuntu so you can easily add support for snaps and the [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/install/snap-store/elementary) just like you'd find on a stock instance of Ubuntu Desktop.
In fact, installing the Plex Media Server snap is as easy as three commands according to the [Snapcraft Website's instructions](https://snapcraft.io/install/plexmediaserver/elementary).

I can't think of any known issues you'd need to be concerned with given what you've said.
If you're current system is based on Ubuntu 18.04 and is working fine then you can reasonably expect the same.
You can always test elementary OS from the installation media as a way to check.
You shouldn't need to worry about hardware compatibility issues like you had with CentOS as that would have had a different and almost certainly older kernel.

Welcome to the community, by the way.
Glad to have you hear and best of luck!

Comment: Thank you! As I gather all my backup information (crontabs, configuration files, scripts, etc.) I have installed elementary on a Parallels VM running on a Mac.  I've installed webmin successfully, and just for grins and giggles, VLC.  Adding the terminal and VLC to the dock are a piece of cake, as is removing the "user apps" I would likely not want on my server.  I install xrdp so I can remote into the server -- from across my house, mostly, so that the box generally sits in the dark, and I sit at the "desktop" when I'm putting things together.  I'm now quite confident this is going to work!